# Javascript array and loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I need help trying to get my code to work. I want to be able to loop my arrays and use the if command to make sure the array is there.

```
arr = ["1","2","3","4"];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   if (string != arr[i]) {
  //do something
   }
}
```

But it does not work. the if command ignores.

```
    var arr = ["150","-75"];

right = righ + "px";
leftpl=left * 1; 
    if (left < 325){        
leftplu = leftpl + 10; leftplus = leftplu + 'px ';
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (leftplus+right != arr[i]){
document.getElementById("new").innerHTML=leftplu+'px ' + righ+'px';
        }
    }
    }
```

or can I put the for loop in the "if (leftplus+right != arr[i])" like "if (leftplus+right != for for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {arr[i]})"

I apologize, for my poor effort to understand. I'm new to javascript and trying to learn.

Comment: "Make sure the array is there"? What does that mean?

Comment: What I said is misunderstanding. What I mean, its if the string finds that array, it does something.

Comment: How does a string find an array...?

Comment: Do you actually have separate variables `leftplu`, `leftpl`, and `leftplus` (if so you should probably come up with different names, if not you have typos) -- also `right` and `righ`?

Comment: Ha, this is simple for my use. No one else would see it. It doesn't bother me what the names are. It was first called var1 var2 var3. As long as I understand it, I don't care.

Comment: lol fair enough. The danger is if it becomes confusing. Right now you do `if (leftplus+right != arr[i])` -- but `leftplus` and `right` are both strings, so you are essentially saying `if ('50px 60px' != "150")` (obviously I made up the numbers in front of px but you get the idea) -- so the code in the if should run everytime and keep overwriting the contents of element `new`. Is that what you see?

Comment: I also mistyped it, it should be "150 0,","-75 0".

Comment: I think you mean "150 0","-75 0" (you've an extra comma after 0) -- and turns out the variables were confusing you. Use `if(leftplu+" "+righ != arr[i])` if you don't want the 'px' in your comparison

Comment: Okay, let me ask this. Is it even possible to complete "!=" to more then one variable? For example:

`if(leftplu+right != "150 0","150 2","150 , 3")`

Comment: Not all at once. You have to combine them using `&&` (meaning and) or `||` (meaning or). In your case I think you want and. `var coords = leftplu + " " + righ; if( coords != "150 0" && coords != "150 2" && coords != "150 3"...) { /* do something */ }`

Comment: Which means only if it doesn't match _any_ of those coordinates, will it then `do something`.

Comment: See.. I was using the && sybmol like this: ` if( coords != "150 0" && "150 1")` and that was my mistake. That worked, so I really appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
string != arr[i]
```

To this:

```
typeof arr[i] != "string"
```

JavaScript is a loosely typed language and therefore has no keyword `string`. Instead, as shown above, you can use the `typeof` operator to obtain the data type of its operand as a string.

With this change, your final code should look like this:

```
arr = ["1","2","3","4"];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   if (typeof arr[i] != "string") {
       //do something
   }
}
```

Comment: Not quite working, but I understand the logic of the your idea. But let me ask, is it possible to create a for loop within a if?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to create a `for` loop within an `if` conditional. However, I'm not sure why the posted code is not working. I updated my answer to include the full code. Is this the code you are using?

Comment: Technically, no. This is just something I wrote that looks very similar. I'm confused as well, It should work, but it's not. It's very aggravating.

Comment: Well, I just tested my code. It's working correctly, so it must be something you're doing differently in your real code. Can you please post that code?

Comment: I'm very confused as to what exactly you're trying to do. You're currently adding two strings with the suffix "px" and comparing them to a numeric string. Perhaps this is what you're trying to accomplish: `if (parseFloat(leftplus)+parseFloat(right) != parseFloat(arr[i]))`

Answer (score 1):

This line:
"leftplus+right"

contains strings like "123px456px" it is pointless to compare these with the array values...

I will guess you meant to add numbers together instead of connecting these strings